# Connection to server blocked for no reason

Tags: ubuntu, networking, vps, connection, internet

I have had a VPS in NL for the past 5-6 years and it's been working great. Now one day I suddenly can't access/ping/anything the VPS from my home connection (tried different computers)

The confusing part is that accessing the server works great when I go directly to the sites I have hosted on it (because they are behind Cloudflare's CDN proxy) or when I try to access the server at work it works good too.

The question is how the heck do I figure out if its my home connection/ISP/router blocking the connection to the VPS or if its the VPS company/software blocking connections FROM my home connection?

Is there any skilled sysadmins out there that can guide me here? I am currently really confused as to where the problem lies.

Answer (score 2):

Start a packet capture on the client and the server and test everything.

- All ISPs available, fixed line and mobile, work and home.
- Use a VPN service to come in from a different provider.
- Determine routes to the instance

  - From your client with traceroute
  - From a different ISP by using a looking glass server
- Review all firewalls and access control lists.

  - At the host level ufw and fail2ban, for example
  - Possibly you have access to firewall services ("security groups") on your infrastructure

If you find proof an ISP isn't getting  you were you need to go, open a support ticket with them.